# Symfony 3 and Nginx throwing 404 on production .php routes

Tags: symfony, nginx

I've recently moved to a new server setup running nginx instead of Apache. From legacy code that's used externally I need a route /assets/js/wiget_load.js.php to be set.

This used to work on Apache but now doesn't on nginx. I'm new to this so I can't work out how this is happening and why it's throwing a nginx 404. This also works fine if I visit /app_dev.php/assets/js/wiget_load.js.php but not on prod. Here's my .conf file:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/mydomain.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/mydomain.key;

    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # # DEV
    # # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           30d;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Request of `/assets/js/wiget_load.js.php` matched the following location:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  return 404;
}
```

> This also works fine if I visit /app_dev.php/assets/js/wiget_load.js.php but not on prod

Yes, because for dev this URI matched `location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$)` and `location ~ \.php$`, and nginx used first found (how it writed in config file).

So, now how to fix... my suggestion is

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files /never_exists_filename /app.php$is_args$args;
}
```

All .php files will route to /app.php and never transered to client even if exists on disk. `try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;` here unsafe becuase if .php file exists on disk - it will be passed to browser as static file.

Comment: "and nginx used first found" --- nginx actually matched it because it's longer.

Comment: No, longest matching prefix rule used only for normal locations. RegExp's locations tested one by one from top to end and stop after first match.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, I thought it's always the length that matters. Thanks!